# Music21 - Python: COnvert musicxml to MIDI, mapping String info to channel

Tags: python, midi, music21, musicxml

I took a look at the music21 documentation, but I don't know if what I am looking for is possible.

For fretted instrument, musicXML can have a  tag.

I am looking to convert musicXML files with String infos in MIDI files, with string ID mapped to the MIDI channel of the notes.

Would that be possible with music21 ?

How it could be set up ?

Thanks for your assistance :)

Comment: Music21 does not currently support fretted information or tablature.  But it's planned for 2018 release.

Comment: @michaelScottCuthbert Oh ok! I thought I was missing something, so thanks for the info!

Comment: I don't think it is implemented. Itt is 2021 now!